# Edittext not possible to get the date settled by user from date picker

Tags: android

I want to popup a date picker dialog when image button being clicked, and then the user selected date will be shown at the edit text field. I followed the guideline from Android developer to use through DialogFragment, and it was succeeded to popup the date picker dialog. User can select the date inside the dialog, but it will be crashed when the user pressed the set button.

In fact I suspected this is the problem from the getContext() in LayoutInflater in the onDateSet because there are the remark saying that "Call required API level 23 (current API : 12)", but I can't figure it out how to fix it.

This is recommended by Android Developers to call getContext() to get the active Context, and not sure why the problem happen.

I have tried to use @TargetApi, but it said this is used for the method only.

Can someone let me know where is the problem in my code?

The logical stated:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.test.testapplication.DatePickerFragment.getContext

DatePickerFragment

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {


final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int YEAR;
int MONTH;
int DAY;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    YEAR = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    MONTH = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    DAY = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, YEAR, MONTH, DAY);
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

    YEAR = year;
    MONTH = monthOfYear;
    DAY = dayOfMonth;

    String dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat, Locale.CHINESE);

    View fragment = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_datepickerdialogfragment, null);
    EditText editText = (EditText) fragment.findViewById(R.id.edittext);
    editText.setText(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
}
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class DPDFActivity extends FragmentActivity {

EditText editText;
ImageButton btn;
DialogFragment datePickerFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_datepickerdialogfragment);

    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
    btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new showDateDialog());
}

public class showDateDialog implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        datePickerFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        datePickerFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create date picker class inside you activity as static for eg i did something like this in my fragment.

```
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    int currentYear;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        currentYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, currentYear, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        if(currentYear-year >=15) {
            CharSequence strDate = null;
            Calendar chosenDate = Calendar.getInstance();
            chosenDate.setTimeInMillis(0);
            chosenDate.set(year, month, day);
            Date date = chosenDate.getTime();
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                    "yyyy-MM-dd");
            strDate = dateFormatter.format(date);

            btnDOB.setText(strDate);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"Selected Year should be mininmum 15 year ago from current year. Please try again.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

define edittext in your activity outside of any methon (class level)

```
private static EditText meditText;
```

use findById() method in activity oncreate() only which can be updated  later.

Comment: Your suggestion is worked that make its easier to understand, and already implemented  to my program. Just one thing I concerned whether we can do it as suggested by Android Developer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to call getContext(). You should be able to use getActivity() here.

```
View fragment = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.activity_datepickerdialogfragment, null);
```

Comment: getActivity() can be used without crash but the date doesn't shown on the edit text after date set. Do you know what went wrong? by the way, do you know why android developer suggest to use getContext() if it doesn't work?

Comment: here,  editText.setText(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));         calendar.getTime() returns an Date object not a string. Try Using  editText.setText(sdf.format(calendar.getTime().getTime())), i know its ugly.

Comment: also not sure why android developer suggest to use getContext().